# Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT Error in API 19 but no in API 23

Tags: android, android-intent

I have code for open explorer like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("file/*");
startActivityForResult(intent,PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE);
```

and it's working if I try in my phone API 23, but when I try in phone API 19.
error like this

```
No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT typ=file/* }
```

how to fix that?

Comment: Change to `"*/*"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no official MIME type that begins with `file/`. If you want to filter by MIME types, you have to use *real* MIME types.

Or, as greenapps suggested in a comment, use `*/*` to accept any sort of content.

> and it's working if I try in my phone API 23, but when I try in phone API 19

On your API Level 23 phone, you installed some app that claims to support a non-existent MIME type that begins with `file/*`.

Answer (score 0):

What phone are you testing it on? Android's Intent documentation suggests that for something as broad as a file/* MIME type

> In this case, you should wrap the GET_CONTENT intent with a chooser (through createChooser(Intent, CharSequence)), which will give the proper interface for the user to pick how to send your data and allow you to specify a prompt indicating what they are doing. You will usually specify a broad MIME type (such as image/* or */*), resulting in a broad range of content types the user can select from.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_GET_CONTENT

By just specifying the kind of data you want and starting the Activity it's does not handle the case where the phone your running on has no app that has an Activity specified to handle that kind of a file.

In that case you may want to suggest to the user to install an application that can handle such an operation